# Second taxonomy is not displayed in the front-end

Tags: wordpress, custom-taxonomy, taxonomy-terms

i had created two taxonomies with register_taxonomy() with same settings

```
register_taxonomy(
    'books',
    'books',
    array(
        'label'             => __( 'Kategorie' ),
        'rewrite'           => array( 'slug' => 'books' ),
        'hierarchical'      => true,
        'show_admin_column' => true,
        'show_ui'           => true,
        'capabilities'      => array(
            'manage_terms' => 'manage_books',
            'edit_terms'   => 'edit_books',
            'delete_terms' => 'delete_books',
            'assign_terms' => 'assign_books',
        )
    )
);

register_taxonomy(
    'genre',
    'genre',
    array(
        'label'             => __( 'Tag' ),
        'rewrite'           => array( 'slug' => 'genre' ),
        'hierarchical'      => true,
        'show_admin_column' => true,
        'show_ui'           => true,
        'capabilities'      => array(
            'manage_terms' => 'manage_genre',
            'edit_terms'   => 'edit_genre',
            'delete_terms' => 'delete_genre',
            'assign_terms' => 'assign_genre',
        )
    )
);
```

If i want to display the terms for books it works but if i want to display the genre taxnomie, i get a null statement.

$books = get_the_terms( $id, 'books');

=> Get all Tags

$genre = get_the_terms( $id, 'genre');

=> Get NULL without any values

Comment: are you registering two taxonomies under same custom post or two?

Comment: You have custom taxonomy `genre` and also CPT as `genre`. Does not that create conflict?

Comment: @Nilambar is right. Check that register_taxonomy function again. So, if you are creating taxonomy for posts you write it as `register_taxonomy('genre', 'posts'...`. Second argument is object type. It may be post, page, attachment, your cpt... So, you have CPT genre, right? Or only books?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add in default capabilities instead of 'manage_genre' to 'manage_categories' same for others, please check below code

```
register_taxonomy(  'genre',
'genre',
 array(
    'label'             => __( 'Tag' ),
    'rewrite'           => array( 'slug' => 'genre' ),
    'hierarchical'      => true,
    'show_admin_column' => true,
    'show_ui'           => true,
    'capabilities'      => array(
        'manage_terms' => 'manage_categories',
        'edit_terms'   => 'manage_categories',
        'delete_terms' => 'manage_categories',
        'assign_terms' => 'edit_posts'
    )
  )
)
```